# Is it possible to modify bash to run one command through another (say a python script)?

Tags: bash, shell, python

I was wondering if it is possible to modify bash such that when I type

```
command --arg1
```

what actually happens is

```
~/prerun.py command --arg1
```

(prerun.py would handle starting command --arg1 itself)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
command () {
    prerun.py some_command "$@"
}
```

Then when you run `command --arg1` it will pass it all on to the prerun.py script.

Comment: Note that a function is recommended above an alias for extensibility purposes.  Passing it variables and whatnot are far more capable.  They can be multiple lines long and allow you to use variables internally.

Comment: make sure you quote `"$@"` so any arguments with whitespace are protected

Comment: 10 years later, glenn your comment is correct.  Edited to add your suggestion!

Answer (score 7):

Define an [alias](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) with the [`alias`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-alias) builtin:

```
alias command='~/prerun.py command'
```